# How to let cron run in two separate time frames on the same day?

Tags: cron

I tried to add a cron in Jenkins and do let the job run only from 12am - 4am and 2pm -12am.

My gut feeling is it should be something like(minutes is not a big concern to me)

0 14-4 * * *

But this throws me an error. I searched around but didn't find a good answer for this. Is this something related to the jenkins i'm using? how can I work it around?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
0 00-04,12-14 * * *
```

your job will run every hour in these ranges: on midnight, 1am, 2am.. 4am. And then again on 12pm, 1pm and 2pm.